# My new approach to wp_enqueue_script

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

OK, i'm trying to eliminate all possible variables for troubleshooting purposes. So instead of in my functions.php, I've dropped this code in my header.php file:

```
<?php $mdgtemplateloc = get_bloginfo( 'template_url' ).'/js/'; ?>
<?php echo '<!-- ' . $mdgtemplateloc . ' --> ?>
<?php wp_enqueue_script( 'hoverIntent', $mdgtemplateloc.'hoverIntent.js', array( 'jquery' ) ); ?>
<?php wp_enqueue_script( 'mdMenuAnimation', $mdgtemplateloc.'mdMenuAnimation.js', array( 'hoverIntent' ) ); ?>
```

The result is a few white space insertions into the source and the comment appears as requested. My understanding was that this would insert something like

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="[url]/js/mdMenuAnimation.js"></script>
```

I want to do this the correct way, but wp_enqueue_script has been giving me NOTHING. I suspect I'm doing something fundamentally wrong, but I can't find it and nothing I find through google or stackoverflow or the wp codex is helping at all.

To clarify, here's what I had before, in the functions.php file:

```
function mdg_setup_scripts() {
  $mdgtemplateloc = get_bloginfo( 'template_url' ).'/js/';
  wp_register_script( 'hoverIntent', get_bloginfo('template_url').'/js/hoverIntent.js', array( 'jquery' ));
  wp_enqueue_script( 'hoverIntent' );
  wp_register_script( 'mdMenuAnimation', $mdgtemplateloc.'mdMenuAnimation.js', array( 'hoverIntent' ));
  wp_enqueue_script( 'mdMenuAnimation' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'mdg_setup_scripts' );
```

This also produced no output that ever called a script. I understand that this second is more like what is supposed to be, but it isn't doing anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`wp_enqueue_script()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) does not output anything. You're using it incorrectly.

You need to create a callback and add it to the `wp_enqueue_scripts` action. Typically this belongs in your **functions.php** file.

Re-read the docs. There are examples of exactly what you are wanting to do.

Comment: Yes, there's this:
`<?php
function my_scripts_method() {
    wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
    wp_register_script( 'jquery', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
}    
 
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method');
?>` 
To be put in the functions.php. I do that, and I get the same exact action (substituting my own script names/locations, of course).

Comment: yes, but no `<script>` tags are showing up. (I have gone back to the older version, which made more sense to me, but I was trying something new)

Comment: GORRAMIT Somewhere along the line I had commented out the add_action line. I don't even have any idea when. I've been banging my head over something that should have been working this whole time if I wasn't such a derp. Thanks for the help, Jason.